# Is Cobalt's "Eater of Birds" considered experimental within the realm of extreme metal?

Tags: metal

Cobalt's [*Eater of Birds*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tdIuqfED_h8) seems to be considered their defining album. I am asking specifically about the [titular song](https://youtu.be/tdIuqfED_h8?t=3582), which is also the final track of the album, but any thoughts on the album itself are appreciated as well.

There seems to be a fair amount of time signature experimentation and strange effects, but many parts sound pretty typical for old-school black metal (I'm reminded of Horna).

Is Cobalt's "Eater of Birds" considered 'experimental' or 'progressive' within its genre?